How to save userid in cisco anyconnect VPN GUI?
Does anyone know if there is a way to configure the cisco vpn so that the userid can be saved in the VPN login GUI?  It is annoying having to input userid and passwd every time. It seems cisco vpn does not allow one to save passwd, but isn't that there should be a way to save the userid?  There are some similar questions on how to save the userid, but so far there does not seem to be an answer that works for my ubuntu. Thanks

Sounds like a good question to ask the Cisco people. I also do not see any Ubuntu version info in your question.
